# Intellij idea Live templates variable run groovy script relation file path

Tags: intellij-idea, live

Live templates -> edit variable.
I can specify groovy file in variable settings: groovyScript("C:/test.groovy")
Where is "home" directory to store my script? i Want something like that: 
groovyScript("test.groovy")
For easy export config to another PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

groovyScript's argument can be either the script text itself or a filename. In the latter case the filename is relative to idea or idea/bin directory. It's probably better to use absolute paths.

In recent IDEA builds you can share live templates by copying them to clipboard (Ctrl+C, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141077)

Comment: I know what i'm asking! "The first argument is a script text that is executed or a path to the file that contains a script." - from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-template-variables.html

Comment: Oops, you're right. I didn't know that! I've changed the answer accordingly.